# Does Visual Studio Development Server cache files apart from the ASPX file locations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I should state upfront that I'm relatively new to web programming, so I might be inadvertently committing some obvious error.

I have this wierd problem when I'm trying to debug a webapp that uses the TinyMCE editor and the fMath plugin. Basically, I need to add some new functionality to the fMath plugin. To do this, I need to debug how TinyMCE and fMath work.

I have added the TinyMCE and fMath files to my ASPX project under a folder called Scripts.

When I run the webapp, both TinyMCE and fMath work as expected.

By way of experimentation, I add some of my own code to the appropriate Javascript functions, set some breakpoints in the code I added, and then run the VS debugger. The debugger never triggers the breakpoints.

I replace the breakpoints with alert() calls and restart debugging. The alert() calls never get triggered either.

To me it looks like there is a separate cache of files which the VS web server is creating, and these files are used for debugging purposes. The files which contain my modifications are displayed in the editor, but some other files are used for the debugger.

What might I be missing here?

Comment: Might be your browser is caching the files, try refresh by pressing `ctrl+F5`

Comment: Nope! Nice try, though. I did the Ctl-F5 and the result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities

tinyMCE plugins have two js files editor_plugin.js and editor_plugin_src.js

If you have used ctrl+f5 you could be editing the wrong one.

You can find out for sure what file is being used by looking at network activity. To do this in chrome, click the options button -> tools -> developer. In the window that pops up select network. Then refresh your browser window. What you should see is the full path of every file being loaded in the browser. This will allow you to locate the correct location of the fmath plugin file being used.

Another problem to watch out for is the compression module that comes with the .net version of tinyMCE. What this does is combine all the plugin files into one file and saves it to disk for faster loading. Every subsequent request by the browser is then served with this one combined file, thus if you change the fmath plugin source file the changes are not reflected in the browser.

You can find out more about this here http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Compressors:.NET

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at this. I had recognized the two different possible files, and I thought that I had specified the editor_plugin_src.js one (presumably not compressed).

Comment: Still working the issue. I switched to CKEditor and had the same problem. I downloaded CKPackager, and then realized that the plugin I need to work with (fMath) may require additional work and research.

Answer (score 0):

From what you tell i assume you are loading on your website the tinymce file `tiny_mce.js`. You could use the developement file `tiny_mce_dev.js` and see if this works out. If it does you have edited the wrong file. In order to make it work for both (production and developement version) you should have both files of a tinymce plugin `editor_plugin.js` and `editor_plugin_src.js` up to date always.